# Grails JSON field missing

Tags: json, rest, grails

I need to create a JSON response in my application that will contain the object's equivalent + additional fields. Here's how the show() method looks like:

```
def show(Long id) {
        verifyUserLoggedIn()

        ScBusinessProcess scBusinessProcess = ScBusinessProcess.get(id)
        BusinessProcess businessProcess =  BusinessProcessTranslator.toREST(scBusinessProcess)
        businessProcess.questions = getQuestions(scBusinessProcess)
        businessProcess.rate = getUserRate();
        businessProcess.totalSteps = calculateTotalSteps(scBusinessProcess);
        businessProcess.usersCurrentStep = 1;
        respond businessProcess
    }
```

The toREST() method copies ScBusinessProcess domain class object into a new BusinessProcess Java object. Next ones are the fields I'm adding manually. So far, everything's been working except the last field that's not being shown in the response (debugger claims that the newly created object contains the field and its passed value). Here's my toREST method:

```
public static BusinessProcess toREST(ScBusinessProcess scBusinessProcess) {
        if (scBusinessProcess == null) return null;
        return new BusinessProcess(
                scBusinessProcess.id(),
                scBusinessProcess.getName(),
                null,
                scBusinessProcess.getDescription(),
                scBusinessProcess.getPromoted(),
                scBusinessProcess.getLikedCount(),
                scBusinessProcess.getDislikedCount(),
                0,
                0,
                0
        );
    }
```

And below, the returned JSON:

```
class   "rest.BusinessProcess"
description "Business Process Description"
dislikes    0
id  1
likes   1
name    "BusinessProcessOne"
promoted    false
questions   []
rate    1
totalSteps  0
```

The usersCurrentStep is missing. What can be the problem? If I need to put more code just say. Also, the Grails version that the application is built on is 3.1.9.

Answer (score 0):

What is the structure of the BusinessProcess class? You can generate JSON of any structure you like if you have the right marshaller - see this link to know more about object marshallers -

http://docs.grails.org/3.0.17/guide/webServices.html#objectMarshallers